# Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_itk.so

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, restart

I ran `tasksel` to install `lamp` server, but I  accidentally delete everything, when I got everything work as before I noticed that apache is not working and here is there message I get while trying to restart the service

The apache2 `configtest` failed.

Output of config test was:

```
   apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_itk.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_itk.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_itk.so: file too short
   Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The Apache error log may have more information.

any sol ?

Comment: Could you provide information of your ubuntu version and your apache version. Have you libapache2-mpm-itk installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try first disabling it

`a2dismod mpm_itk`

and then re-enabling it

`a2enmod mpm_itk`

It could be that you have mpm_prefork module installed in which case

`a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_itk`